# How can I draw the intersection of a cone and a plane?

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, intersection

I have a cone and a plane `myQ = x - 4 y + z + 4 == 0;`. How can I draw the intersection of the cone and the plane `myQ`?

```
  Clear["Global`*"]
pA = {2, 3, 0};
myP = 2 x + y + 2 z - 1 == 0;
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[x \[Minus] 4  y + z + 4 == 0, {x, y, z}];
pH = RegionNearest[ImplicitRegion[myP, {x, y, z}]]@pA;
d = Sqrt[5^2 - EuclideanDistance[pA, pH]];
reg2 = Cone[{pA, pH}, d];
r2 = RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2];
Graphics3D[{Gray, Opacity[0.5], reg2}, Boxed -> False]

Show[Region[Style[r2, Cyan]]]
```

[image]

[image]

```
Show[Region[Style[reg1, Red]], Region[Style[reg2, Blue]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `PlotRange` in `Region`.

```
Show[Region[Style[reg1, Opacity[.3], Red], PlotRange -> 8], 
 Region[Style[reg2, Opacity[.2], Blue]], Region[Style[r2, Cyan]]]
```

[image]

- Add `BoundaryStyle`.

```
Show[Region[Style[reg1, Opacity[.3], Red], PlotRange -> 8], 
 Region[Style[reg2, Opacity[.2], Blue]], 
 RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion@r2, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive@{Dashed, Thick}, PlotStyle -> Cyan]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can I get the equation of the parabol is intersection of the cone and the plane?